# Open a web browser with search criteria using Flutter

Tags: url, flutter

I have an app that has a list of hotels, I am looking to have the hotels clickable and open the default browser and search for that hotel.

I have found lots of on-line help about opening specific pages, maps and other ways of opening a site. But I cannot find anywhere that shows you how to open the browser and automatically search for something.

I am using the url_launcher package. 
How is this done please? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the url_launcher package to open a search engine in a web browser and then input the hotel name you're looking for as a query
eg.

```
var url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=$selectedHotelName";
launch(url);
```